# unable to break out of outer loop in golang

Tags: go

the following is my function where im trying to Validate the ID's and unable to return values from the inner loop.

```
func Validate(id int, tn []Node) int {
    var value int
    for _, j := range tn {

        if id == j.ID {
            println(id, j.ID)
            value = j.ID
            println("aa", value)
            break
        } else {
            if j.Children != nil {
                ValidateID(id, j.Children)
            }

        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Comment: There's only one loop in your code: the `for ... range` loop. Everything else is just if statements. `break` applies to the for loop.

Comment: Specifically what doesn't work about this? You say "inner loop" and "outer loop" but there's only 1 loop.

Comment: I think I can guess: `ValidateID` should read `Validate` and you want to return the value if you find the ID in a child node?

Comment: Yes, you most likely have to process the return value of `ValidateID()` which may mean to return early. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note on code: it seems like you either return `id` or 0 depending whether you find the id. Maybe you should return a bool instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to return whether the ID was found in any node of a tree. Your code is almost there, but you need to check whether the recursive call finds it. Using `return` rather than `break` makes the code simpler.

I removed the `print` statements, which I guess are there for debugging purposes.

I also replaced the return value with a `bool` (the original code either returned the ID itself or 0 to represent not-found), and removed the `j.Children == nil` test (the code returns false for an empty slice:

```
// ValidateID reports whether id exists in a tree of nodes.
func ValidateID(id int, tn []Node) bool {
    for _, j := range tn {
        if id == j.ID || ValidateID(id, j.Children) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Note if you want to actually return something other than a bool from the target node, I'd make the function return two values: that which you are interested and the bool that says whether the ID was found. Relying on sentinel values like 0 is discouraged by ["Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#multiple-returns).

Comment: This made a lot of sence. Thanks a lot Paul